# How to create CurrentProject.connection

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have seen hundreds of code examples on how to assign the `currentproject.connection` to an `adodb.connection` but nowhere have I seen how to create the `currentproject.connection` in the first place.  I like the idea of being able to create a single connection but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create `CurrentProject.Connection`, at least not directly.  Access itself creates and manages it within the application session as the connection to the database or ADP (the `CurrentProject`) which is open in that session.

So with a database open, you can go to the Immediate window and interact with the `Connection` ...

```vba
? TypeName(CurrentProject.Connection)
Connection
? CurrentProject.Connection.Provider
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
? Left(CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString, 90) ' just a portion of it '
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\share\Access\Database2.accd
Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM Dual;")
? rs(0)
 1
```

However if you close the database but not the Access application session, `CurrentProject.Connection` is no longer usable (That makes sense because there's nothing to connect to.) ...

```vba
? TypeName(CurrentProject.Connection)
Nothing
```